# Is the time complexity of this solution O(logn)?

Tags: python, time-complexity, big-o

I have written the following solution for a challenge but I am not sure about its time complexity:

```
def ASCIIConversion(string): 
    newStr = ''

    for chr in string:
        if chr.isspace(): 
            newStr = newStr + ' '
        else:
            newStr += str(ord(chr))

    return newStr
```

Is the complexity of the program, O(logn), because of the else statement?

Comment: you iterate through the array of strings, that should be `O(n)`. all statements inside the loop are constant time, including if and else.

Comment: I am actually learning Big O notation right now, and it seems that I have some misconceptions. Thank you!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This solution is still O(n). I'm not entirely sure why the else statement would affect this, actually. You're performing one operation on every character in the string.

Even though for each character, you're performing multiple instructions (comparisons, etc.), you may think the complexity is something like O(3n), but of course you disregard the coefficient. I'm sure you know this, but for people viewing this question in the future, confused about the else statement, this might help.

Comment: I am actually learning Big O notation right now, and it seems that I have some misconceptions. Thank you for the thorough answer!

Comment: @cpit no problem! As a general rule of thumb, you can just count the amount of for- and while-loops and work it out from there.

Answer (score 7):

The time complexity in worst case is calculated as below(suppose string max length is n):

```
newStr = ''  # will be done once so 1 time.

for chr in string: # is iterating on the input with max length of n so n times.
    if chr.isspace(): # will be checked once it is in the loop so 1 time per each iteration.
        newStr = newStr + ' ' # also once per iteration if the if condition is satisfied
    else: # will be chehcked once per iteration
        newStr += str(ord(chr)) # if else is satisfied

return newStr # will be done 1 time.
```

we will assumes that the constant times are c so:

> `Time complexity = 1 + n(c*c + c*c) + 1 = 2+Cn => O(n)`

Comment: @TrebuchetMS Thanks. Done :)

Answer (score 0):

Irrespective of if-else condition, loop iterate through each character of string so time complexity is O(n).